# How to configure Sonar runner property to read junit reports for both android unit test and junit test as well

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, sonar-runner

My have project have few android unit test case and few junit test case and using android gradle plugin it generates two different reports.

While configuring sonar-runner properties for project I found that **'sonar.junit.reportsPath'** property can be set to make junit report data avail to sonar runner. I made below configuration in my build.gradle file.

```
sonarRunner {
            sonarProperties {
                //... 
                property 'sonar.junit.reportsPath', 'build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/'
                //... 
            }
          }
```

But it allows one path at a time. Is it possible to "sonar.junit.reportsPath" to include both the reports.

Below is my project structure:

[image]

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @pablo not so far

Answer (score 0):

There is a sonarqube property for Integration tests:

```
property 'sonar.jacoco.itReportPath'
```